MongoDB finding document containing part of string got some problems
models/userModel.js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
   {
        name: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
    },
    username: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
          unique: true,
    },
    },
)

controllers/userController.js
export const findUserConversation = async(req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.params 

    try{ 
        let user 
        
        user = await User.find({$or: [
            { name: { $regex: name, $options: 'i'} },
            { username: { $regex: name, $options: 'i'} }
        ]}).select("-password").select("-updatedAt")
        console.log(user)

        if(!user){
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" })
        }

        res.status(200).json(user)
    } catch(error){
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
        console.log("Error in getUserProfile: ", error.message);
    }
}

I have a problem that I would like to write a controller that would return the result when part of the query param value exists on the User model either name or username and I tried to type a string that not exists in the model the error message could not be read instead returning an empty array only. I am wondering what is the best way to return the result from the database if part of the string exists in specific fields
I searched and searched but could not find out the best solution to fix the issue.

The find method returns an empty array ([]) when there are no matches for the provided query filter. So, you may want to check for an empty array also.

for the desired response, please use findOne instead of find.

Instead of if(!user) you need if(!user.length).

For the given query parameter, how many documents you would expect ? Always a single document irrespective of the number of matching documents, or as many documents it may find. The same in functional words, are you fetching a single user or a group of users ? Please note that #regex  has the potential to match more than one document.
